# ACTIVE DIRECTORY MIGRATION TO CLOUD

Tags: azure-active-directory, active-directory, migration, cloud, virtual-machine

I have 3 Active directories servers on premises  ( DNS and DHCP installed on those servers ) , and im migrating all my application stack to the cloud.

Is it recommended to migrate AD server
s as well or retain them on prem ? And what would be the impact on my Dns server and DHcP server  if i migrate them ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your Domains Controller on-premises, you need your users and computer to authenticate, and you cannot depend on the VPN connection.

If you have some VM on Azure and these VMs require to authenticate in your domain, the best practice indicates that you must have a domain controller server on each site (Azure will be your remote site).

Comment: If the connection to the Cloud is with MPLS , that wouldn't solve the problem ?

Comment: If you are 100% sure that your internet connection never goes down, go ahead... because when you lose your Internet Connection you will only be able to do local jobs on the PCs.